# ng-message disappears when $error changes while animation is in progress

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

I have a form with a custom async validator. I recognized that sometimes the error message disappears even if the value in an input field is invalid.

I was able to reproduce the problem with a normal validator: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjqJJR)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="FormController" layout-padding>
  <form name="inputForm">
    <md-input-container>
      <input type="text" name="inputValue" custom-validator ng-model="model.value" />
      <label>input value</label>
      <div ng-messages="inputForm.inputValue.$error">
        <div ng-message="custom-validator">This field is invalid</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container> 
    <div>inputForm.inputValue.$error = {{inputForm.inputValue.$error | json}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

app.controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    value: '',
    asyncValue: ''
  }
}]);

app.directive('customValidator', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators['custom-validator'] = function(model, view) {
        return (model.length % 2) == 0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

When I type in a value slow the error message correctly appears and disappears. But when I type fast the error message disappers even if the input is invalid. It seems that the problem occurs when the $error value changes while the animation of the error message is still in progress.

Is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an angular bug. It got fixed in 1.4.7.